# How to set last 2 months as default filter in a power bi dashboard

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, dashboard

The user when opening the dashboard needs to see the last 2 months filtered with slicer not selected

if user select any date in slicer, then the graphic should be filtered according to the slicer (not only 2 months)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative data filter to show the last two months of data on your report. This will track over the time without needing to update the date.

[image]

What you can then do if you need the user to put in their own date range it to use a bookmark to remove the date filter to the full date range, which the user can select.

[image]

Using two bookmarks one to clear the data range and one to show the last two months. You can layer the bookmarks and control the visuality, and even the slicer type if required.

[image]